# Is the set of all nowhere differentiable functions on $C[0,1]$ countable?

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces, baire-category, separable-spaces

I know this is a dense set, but is it countable?

Answer (score 2):

No. For example, if $W$ is any nowhere differentiable function, then $W(x)+c$ is as well, for any real number $c$.